# Is it possible to configure the logs with WARN, ERROR, INFO logging keys to ease the burden to monitor the system?

Tags: mongodb, logging

Is there a way to set a logging system to print message level and type to easily understand when there is a problem with mongo?

I saw that sometimes it prints information worth attention but that are not labeled to easily recognize them, as for example: warning, error, info, etc.

```html
2019-03-18T14:57:06.683+0100 I REPL_HB  [replexec-0] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 3) to 10.100.xxx.xxx:27117, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
2019-03-18T14:57:12.683+0100 I ASIO     [Replication] Connecting to 10.100.60.138:27117
2019-03-18T14:57:14.852+0100 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.100.xxx.xxx:53844 #15 (11 connections now open)
2019-03-18T14:57:14.852+0100 I NETWORK  [conn15] received client metadata from 10.100.xxx.xxx:53844 conn15: { driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.4" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
```

Comment: it's labeled by default

the I (information) in the logs is stand for severity level

the rests are F(fatal),E(error),W(warning),D(debug)

Comment: So easy? Thanks. But it is all "Info". As you see below some messages are actually errors or at least warnings

Comment: is that want you want? if yes then I should change my comment into answers

Comment: if your logs only give "Info" that's mean mongodb only consider it as info. if you want  more detail logs you could change the verbosity method or use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#client-data

Comment: I was expecting for some of them to be at least warnings:

2019-03-18T15:32:47.218+0100 I REPL     [replication-0] We are too stale to use x.x.x.x:27117 as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: Timestamp(1550252895, 1) is
 before their earliest timestamp: Timestamp(1552444297, 1) for 1min until: 2019-03-18T15:33:47.218+0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the common format for mongo log lines are

`<timestamp> <severity> <component> [<context>] <message>`

and what you mean by: warning, error, info, etc.

are already there by default (severity)

the severity codes are

```
Level   Description
F       Fatal- The database error has caused the database to no longer be accessible
E       Error - Database errors which will stop DB execution.
W       Warning - Database messages which explains potentially harmful behaviour of DB.
I       Informational - Messages just for information purpose like ‘A new connection accepted’.
D       Debug - Mostly useful for debugging the DB errors
```

you could read more about decoding the logs line [here](https://severalnines.com/blog/decoding-mongodb-error-logs) or [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/)